# Set post title from two meta fields

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, title

In a custom post type I have post titles disabled, however in the list of posts and in the slug it just shows the title as "auto-draft". I want to automatically take two pieces of post-meta and make then the title and the slug.

I thought this would work, but I can't make it happen:

```
function set_event_title( $data , $postarr ) {
  if($data['post_type'] == 'events') {
    $event_date = get_post_meta($post_id,'event_datetime',true);
    $event_venue = get_post_meta($post_id, 'venue_name' , true);
    $event_title = $event_venue . ' - ' . $event_date;
    $post_slug = sanitize_title_with_dashes ($event_title,'','save');
    $post_slugsan = sanitize_title($post_slug);

    $data['post_title'] = $post_title;
    $data['post_name'] = $post_slugsan;
  }
  return $data;
}

add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'set_event_title' , '99', 2 );
```

Anyone know how I might get it to do its thing correctly?

Comment: To clarify a little: I want to string two pieces of meta together to make the title and then sanitize that title (twice, actually) to create the slug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using wrong variable on the following line:

```
$data['post_title'] = $post_title;
```

you should use $event_title in $post_title as following:

```
$data['post_title'] = $event_title;
```

Also Get Post ID from $postarr parameter.

**Updated Code :**

```
function set_event_title( $data , $postarr ) {
  if($data['post_type'] == 'events') {
    $event_date = get_post_meta($postarr['ID'],'event_datetime',true);
    $event_venue = get_post_meta($postarr['ID'], 'venue_name' , true);
    $event_title = $event_venue . ' - ' . $event_date;
    $post_slug = sanitize_title_with_dashes ($event_title,'','save');
    $post_slugsan = sanitize_title($post_slug);

    $data['post_title'] = $event_title;
    $data['post_name'] = $post_slugsan;
  }
  return $data;
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'set_event_title' , '10', 2 );
```

For more information on this filter visit [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense that I needed to call the right variable containing the post object.

This still isn't working for me though...

Comment: @Eckstein Try changing the filter priority. I have changed it in my code.

Comment: Hmm, still not working. Do I need to use something else besides wp_insert_post_data maybe?

Comment: The code that i have entered as answer is working for me..

Comment: ARGR! It was the stupid variable. Thanks for catching it, I hate dumb mistakes.

Comment: I'm just realizing that this is only updating the title on post update and not when a new post is created for the first time. Anyone know how to make it work for new posts as well?

Comment: @Eckstein : How is it possible to make this work with _new_ posts? Where would the meta data come from?

Comment: It's been a while since I got this working so my memory is fuzzy, but you would need to first publish the post to the database and then hook into the save_post action (which is fired after the post is created for the first time).

Answer (score 1):

I found that the previous answer, as stated in the comments, only works when saving an existing post and not new posts. The below will work for new posts and existing posts.

```
// func that is going to set our title of our customer magically
function w2w_customers_set_title( $data , $postarr ) {

    // We only care if it's our customer
    if( $data[ 'post_type' ] === 'w2w-customers' ) {

        // get the customer name from _POST or from post_meta
        $customer_name = ( ! empty( $_POST[ 'customer_name' ] ) ) ? $_POST[ 'customer_name' ] : get_post_meta( $postarr[ 'ID' ], 'customer_name', true );

        // if the name is not empty, we want to set the title
        if( $customer_name !== '' ) {

            // sanitize name for title
            $data[ 'post_title' ] = $customer_name;
            // sanitize the name for the slug
            $data[ 'post_name' ]  = sanitize_title( sanitize_title_with_dashes( $customer_name, '', 'save' ) );
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'w2w_customers_set_title' , '99', 2 );
```

It first checks for the title in the `$_POST` variable, which is where it would come from most of the time. If it is not there, it will pull it from the `post_meta`, which will handle things like Quick Edits.