# Define a post's title and slug from Custom Fields

Tags: custom-field, slug

This question is relate to another one on WPSE:
[Set post title from two meta fields](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94364/set-post-title-from-two-meta-fields/138059#138059)

I am looking for a way to define a WP custom post type's **title** and **slug** from a *custom field* (i.e. first name and last name). Such that if I enter "John" in the fname field and "Doe" in the lname field, the title would be "John Doe" and the slug would be "john-doe".

The solution offered on thread linked above works but it requires that I "save draft" first before I hit "publish". If I click on "publish" right away, the post title is nothing but a single dash/hyphen "-" and the slug is the post ID.

Anyone know how to make it work without the need to "save draft" first?

--- Update ---
Here's the code I'm using. It's based on the linked thread above.

```
function my_set_empname_title( $data , $postarr ) {
    if($data['post_type'] == 'employees') {
        $emp_fname = get_post_meta($postarr['ID'], 'emp_first_name', true);
        $emp_lname = get_post_meta($postarr['ID'], 'emp_last_name', true);
        $new_title = "$emp_fname" . '-' . "$emp_lname";
        $post_slug = sanitize_title_with_dashes($new_title, '', $context = 'save');
        $post_slugsan = sanitize_title($post_slug);
        $data['post_title'] = $new_title;
        $data['post_name'] = $post_slugsan;
    }
    return $data;
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'my_set_empname_title' , '99', 2 );
```

Comment: The solution in the linked question does not require me to post a draft first. Please explain your question more thoroughly and explain how it is not a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using? Maybe the issue is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: @czerspalace
I updated my original post with the code.

Comment: @s_ha_dum
As I've explained in the original post above, I am unable to get the desired results without doing a "save draft" first. I've included the code I'm using.

With regard to the similarity with the linked question - I tried posting a follow-up to that thread (by commenting) but I kept getting the "you need to have a reputation of 50" or something like that. I also got the suggestion to post a new question - which is what I did.

Comment: You can't get_post_meta from a post that doesn't exist yet. You have to get the first and last name using their form field names.

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing

```
 $emp_fname = get_post_meta($postarr['ID'], 'emp_first_name', true);
 $emp_lname = get_post_meta($postarr['ID'], 'emp_last_name', true);
```

with

```
$emp_fname = $_POST['emp_first_name'];
$emp_lname = $_POST['emp_last_name'];
```

Replace the $_POST array keys with whatever the field name is on your form